# Promises.all() - how to check if all return undefined

Tags: javascript, promise

In the following code, I want to check if the `promisesArray` returns any data.

```
const promisesArray = [this.loadData1(),this.loadData2()]

Promise.all(promisesArray).then(() => {
 console.log('promises.all callback -> ', promisesArray[0])
}
```

The above `console.log` can produce the following:

```
Promise {<fulfilled>: undefined}
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: undefined
```

If I do not specify index 0, it repeats the same output for both function calls passed to `Promises.all`.

I am trying to access the `undefined` value in both the responses but not sure how to with with each key being a multi-dimensional array.

If anyone has any ideas on how to easily check if both functions result in `undefined` I would be very grateful.

Comment: Don't log the `promisesArray`, log the *result* of the promise that `Promise.all()` created!

Comment: @Bergi Thanks a million! This should be the answer. It is the simplest to implement.

Answer (score 2):

```
Promise.all(promisesArray)
  .then((res) => res.every((r) => r === undefined))
  .then((isUndefined) => {
    // if isUndefined is true then all promises returned undefined
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using async / await syntax:

```
const results = await Promise.all([this.loadData1(),this.loadData2()]);

if (results.every(r => r === undefined)) {
  console.log('No data!');
}
```